# JQuery - How to get page from url after all page loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the whole page with jquery like this:

```
$.get($("#url").val(), function(response) {});
```

But the response doesn't have the whole page. This mean it doesn't wait external links, image, etc while loaded.

So, how can get all pages with external links images etc?

Comment: you can only get what the server outputs as html. If there are other elements loaded into that page using javascript you need to use a headless browser to render it first and parse the rendered version

Comment: I'm using this code for chrome extension development.So I need to handle with javascript

Comment: That doesn't change the problem. You need an environment to run the headless browser in and be able to communicate with. Can set it in your local host for development. Or take a look at running chrome in pupeteer

Comment: Why not just load the page into a hidden iframe first, and then rip the html?

Comment: Nothing to change.The page come from external url and javascript created part of page.

Comment: Is there any website like this; I post the url and it return full page? @charlietfl